# URL query string rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, query-string, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file but not sure how to get it working. I want to convert this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/userskill/?lvl=100k
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/?lvl=100k
```

The underlying page would ultimately be `http://www.example.com/home.html?lvl=100k`. How can I add a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of the htaccess start with putting the RewriteEngine to on

```
RewriteEngine On
```

After that you can add your rewrite rule. Which will be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^userskill/$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The QSA part copies the query string from the url.

For more information see

http://forums.devshed.com/apache-development-15/question-about-query-string-in-a-rewrite-url-htaccess-557476.html

http://vikrant_labde.blogspot.com/2008/07/querystring-in-htaccess-match-question.html